# Stop and close all processes after exit

Tags: c#

Is there any method to free all of the memory and stop all the related task from the task manager?
I used the below code but it just closes the application, and some task like `chromedriver` is still in the task manager.

```
private void toolStripButton7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult x; 
    x = MessageBox.Show("Do You Want to Exit?","Exit",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (x == DialogResult.Yes)
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: What tasks are you trying to close? Have you started them yourself or are they started by some other way?

Comment: Standard chrome problem, google "chromedriver does not exit" for relevant hits.

Comment: @PoulBak there are the different tasks which are started by the program. I can make a method for each one to close them off. but I want to know is there any shortcut for it?

Comment: @HansPassant Are you telling is it a chrome bug? and there is no way to solve that?

Comment: If you have references to the processes, you can call each process's Exit method.

Comment: This tends to happen when programmers don't realize that WebBrowser attempts to emulate an old IE version.  They switch to CefSharp and now have two problems.  Do avoid forcing SO users to guess so much, you can't get the help you need if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using System;
..
..
..

```
Environment.Exit(0); 0 for Successful process completion.
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. it's work. but it gets to stop working windows after I want to close the program

Comment: using System.Diagnostics;
 foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("Your process name from task manager"))
            {
                proc.Kill();
            }

Comment: var cromeProcessCollection = Process.GetProcesses().
                                 Where(pr => pr.ProcessName == "chromedriver"); // kill all cromedriver processes

foreach (var process in cromeProcessCollection)
{
     process.Kill();
} // This will use to kill all the cromedriver processes if you are looking. Hope this will help you